# PL/SQL error in Oracle Application Express

Tags: sql, oracle, function, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to make a package in OAE, with a function, a procedure and a cursor. When i am trying to run it, i have the following error

> Error at line 21: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CURSOR" when
>   expecting one of the following: end not pragma final instantiable
>   order overriding static member constructor map

This si my code:

```
 create or replace package PACKAGEPROIECT as

procedure DEL_BANCA (
   p_banid.id_banca%TYPE) IS
BEGIN 
  DELETE FROM banci_pnu
  WHERE id_banca=p_banid;
  IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20203, 'Nicio banca nu a fost stearsa din baza de date');
  END IF;
  END DEL_BANCA;
BEGIN
    PACKAGEPROIECT.creste_credit(1,20,'ipotecar');
END;


function formatNume (p_nume IN VARCHAR, p_prenume IN VARCHAR)
    RETURN VARCHAR IS
BEGIN
    RETURN p_nume || ' ' || p_prenume;
END;
    CURSOR c_toticlientii IS
    SELECT nume,prenume FROM clienti
    v_formatareNume varchar(70);
BEGIN
  FOR v_clientRecord IN c_toticlientii
  LOOP v_formatareNume := formatNume(v_clientRecord.nume, v_clientRecord.prenume);
  INSERT INTO temp_table(fname) VALUES (v_formatareNume);
END LOOP;
END formatNume; 
COMMIT;
END;
```

What i am doing wrong here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the **CURSOR** in the **package spec** on top, i.e. **before the declaration of functions and procedures.**

The same order applies even to an **anonymous block**.

I wrote an article about it here http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/07/07/order-of-item-list-in-declaration-part-of-plsql-anonymous-block-pls-00103/

Following is the order of the item list in the declaration part :

- Item list of  variables, cursors, types, subtypes, constants etc.
- Functions.
- Procedures.

Comment: Thank you! Now i am reading your article and i will try to solve this problem.